# How to install `*-utils` manuals in GNU Emacs on Mac OS X?

Tags: documentation

I've been using GNU manuals of `core-utils` and `find-utils` and so on in GNU Emacs when I am using GNU Linux.

They are default after installing GNU Emacs on many GNU Linux distributions.  After open GNU Emacs and `C-h i` I'll find the `core-utils` and `find-utils` doc if I installed `core-utils` and `find-utils` on my Linux.

On Mac, I cannot find the `core-utils` and `find-utils` docs.  I've heard that Mac uses FreeBSD as its kernel.  So I am wondering whether there is a `*-utils` doc that I can install in Emacs, or there is a way to install the `*-utils` docs of GNU Linux on a Macbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the Homebrew package manager for macOS from https://brew.sh/.  This can simply install all manner of useful software including GNU Coreutils which will come with the associated info documentation.  Emacs' info should then automatically detect the new info pages and add them to the toplevel info directory.

There are other alternatives to Homebrew such as MacPorts (https://www.macports.org/) exist that will do something similar.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, are their any *-utils tool chains on Mac OS X?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "*-utils tool chains".  `brew search | grep -- -utils` lists a bunch of things but none of them are tool chains.  Other tool chains a certainly available for macOS though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe homebrew does not provide GNU core-utils or find-utils.

Comment: Oh, it does, the packages are just named "coreutils" and "findutils" without the hyphen.